# Cache video blob url src?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, blob

I have a `<video>` with a blob `src` such as `https://f1.media.brightcove.com/9/1752604059001/1752604059001_5550683509001_5550679964001.m3u8?pubId=1752604059001&videoId=5550679964001.`.

I'm trying to cache this blob using `window.URL.createObjectURL(src)` where `src` is the url above. However, I keep getting this error:

> Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Apparently I need to first convert this blob `src` into a blob object and then pass that in to the function. Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: For dash I would recommend looking into the reference dash player: https://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.4.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/

Comment: Not sure what dash is. Using videojs

Answer (score -1):

You are right `window.URL.createObjectURL(src)` requires a Blob or File object.

This should work.

```
var src = "https://f1.media.brightcove.com/9/1752604059001/1752604059001_5550683509001_5550679964001.m3u8?pubId=1752604059001&videoId=5550679964001"
var file = new Blob(
                      [src],
                      {"type" : "application/x-mpegURL"});
var value = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Here's some more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: Have you actually tried to see if this works? You are only encapsulating the three letters "src" in a blob which obviously is not a valid video, neither would referencing the url as only the URI would be encapsulated.